# Marking Notifications as Read with JS/Ajax API

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, notifications, csrf

I implemented django-notifications into my site and its working quite well (https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications).
The only and I hope last problem I Got is that the Notifications are never marked as read. There is a possibility to do it with an API call and so I wrote something in JS. Im able to GET the Data but I cannot change/POST them since I always get an 403. I can check/uncheck the Boolean in the Admin-Page but I cannot do it with the API Call. Does anybody have an Idea what I can do? The "documentation" is just one site on Github. The makers only made some short examples without a lot of Context.

My code:

```
$(".notiBla").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:("/inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/?max=3&mark_as_read=false/"),
    dataType:'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "unread_list",
    success:function(response){
      response.unread_list[0].unread=false
      console.log(response.unread_list[0].unread)
    }
});
});
```

this returns a 403 since im not allowed to do POST. When I use Get it shows me the data correctly but this is useless since I need to change the data... 
Does anybody know the answer or another way to accomplish my goal?

OK I just found a error message for this. It says:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/
[05/May/2017 19:38:28] "POST /inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/?max=3&mark_as_read=false/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2502
```

But im still kinda lost since I don't know where the CSRF is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> AJAX¶
>
> While the above method can be used for AJAX POST requests, it has some inconveniences: you have to remember to pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request. For this reason, there is an alternative method: on each XMLHttpRequest, set a custom X-CSRFToken header to the value of the CSRF token. This is often easier, because many JavaScript frameworks provide hooks that allow headers to be set on every request.
>
> First, you must get the CSRF token. How to do that depends on whether or not the CSRF_USE_SESSIONS setting is enabled.
>
> Acquiring the token if CSRF_USE_SESSIONS is False¶
>
> The recommended source for the token is the csrftoken cookie, which will be set if you’ve enabled CSRF protection for your views as outlined above.
>
> Note
>
> The CSRF token cookie is named csrftoken by default, but you can control the cookie name via the CSRF_COOKIE_NAME setting.
>
> The CSRF header name is HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN by default, but you can customize it using the CSRF_HEADER_NAME setting.
>   Acquiring the token is straightforward:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

> The above code could be simplified by using the JavaScript Cookie library to replace getCookie:

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
```

> Note
>
> The CSRF token is also present in the DOM, but only if explicitly included using csrf_token in a template. The cookie contains the canonical token; the CsrfViewMiddleware will prefer the cookie to the token in the DOM. Regardless, you’re guaranteed to have the cookie if the token is present in the DOM, so you should use the cookie!
>   Warning
>
> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrf_token template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces setting of the cookie: ensure_csrf_cookie().
>   Acquiring the token if CSRF_USE_SESSIONS is True¶
>
> If you activate CSRF_USE_SESSIONS, you must include the CSRF token in your HTML and read the token from the DOM with JavaScript:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript">
// using jQuery
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
</script>
```

> Setting the token on the AJAX request¶
>
> Finally, you’ll have to actually set the header on your AJAX request, while protecting the CSRF token from being sent to other domains using settings.crossDomain in jQuery 1.5.1 and newer:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
// these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
}
});
```

Simply saying, just serve the getCookie function in a js file and set csrftoken variable.
Then add the ajaxSetup function, and that shoul do the trick.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. The answer works. I don't get the 403 but the Data does not change. Like everything stays the same. When I do console.log after the success it shows me unread = false but when I reload the Page it is again true...

Comment: Thanks. The answer's right in the Django documentation. About that unread = true.. I can't actually say anything about that without further data. The answer just covers the csrf token auth part. You could show me the view this ajax request is calling.

Answer (score 1):

To make an Ajax POST to a Django view you need to pass a CSRF token: add this key to your .ajax() object:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
```

Django's `{{ csrf_token }}` template variable will output a token string e.g. `"mytoken123456789"`. Not to be confused with the template tag `{% csrf_token %}` that goes inside `<form>` elements, which outputs an HTML input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='mytoken123456789' />
```

Comment: im working with django forms so I cannot put type,name,value. Thanks for the answer anyway. It worked with Fazils answer...